# веб сервис java + c#. Наступаю на собственные грабли!

Tags: java, c#, winforms, hibernate, java-ee

Товариши, пишу веб сервис На Java, клиентская часть на С#, также применяю фреймворк hibernate. 
Пример класса модели:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "garages") 
public class Garage implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String decription;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")

    private Owner owner;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "garage")
    private List<Car> cars;

    public Garage() {
    }

    public Garage(int id, String decription, Owner owner, List<Car> cars) {
        this.decription = decription;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDecription() {
        return decription;
    }

    public void setDecription(String decription) {
        this.decription = decription;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}

@Entity @Table(name = "owners") 
public class Owner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Car> ownerCars;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Garage> ownerGarages;

    public Owner() {
    }

    public Owner(int id, List<Car> ownerCars, List<Garage> ownerGarages) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ownerCars = ownerCars;
        this.ownerGarages = ownerGarages;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Car> getOwnerCars() {
        return ownerCars;
    }

    public void setOwnerCars(List<Car> ownerCars) {
        this.ownerCars = ownerCars;
    }

    public List<Garage> getOwnerGarages() {
        return ownerGarages;
    }

    public void setOwnerGarages(List<Garage> ownerGarages) {
        this.ownerGarages = ownerGarages;
    }
    }
```

Реализация DAO:

```
public class OwnerDaoImpl implements OwnerDao {

    private Session session = null;

    @Override
    public void addOwner(Owner owner) {
            openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
            session.save(owner);
             closeSessionAndCommit();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Owner> getAllOwners() {
           openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
            List<Owner> owners = session.createQuery("from Owner").list();
            closeSessionAndCommit();
            return (ArrayList)owners;  
    }

    @Override
    public Owner getOwnerForGarageId(int idGarage) {
            openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Garage where id = :param");
            query.setParameter("param", idGarage);
            Garage garage = (Garage) query.uniqueResult();
            closeSessionAndCommit();
            return garage.getOwner();
    }

    @Override
    public Owner getOwnerForCarId(int idCar) {
            openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Car where id = :param");
            query.setParameter("param", idCar);
            Car car = (Car) query.uniqueResult();
            closeSessionAndCommit();
            return car.getOwner();
    }

     private void openSessionAndBeginTransaction()
    {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void closeSessionAndCommit()
    {
          session.getTransaction().commit();
          session.close();
    }

@Override
public ArrayList<Garage> getListGaragesForOwnerId(int ownerId) {
       openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Car where owner_id = :param");
        query.setParameter("param", ownerId);
        List<Garage> result = query.list();
        closeSessionAndCommit();
        return (ArrayList) result;
}

    @Override
    public Owner getOwnerForName(String name) {
        openSessionAndBeginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Owner where name = :param");
        query.setParameter("param", name);
        Owner result = (Owner) query.uniqueResult();
        return result;
    }
}
```

И сам сервис:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "GaragesServices")
public class GarageServices implements CarServiceInterface, GarageServiceInterface, OwnerServiceInterface {

    CarDao carDao = new CarDaoImpl();
    GarageDao garageDao = new GarageDaoImpl();
    OwnerDao ownerDao = new OwnerDaoImpl();
    Sender postSender = new Sender();

/**
 *
 * @param garage
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public void addGarage(@WebParam(name = "garage") Garage garage) {

    garageDao.addGarage(garage);
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Garage> getAllGarages() {
        return garageDao.getAllGarages();
}

/**
 *
 * @param ownerId
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Garage> getListGaragesForOwnerId(@WebParam(name = "ownerId") int ownerId) {
        return garageDao.getListGaragesForOwnerId(ownerId);
}

/**
 *
 * @param idCar
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public Garage getGarageForCarId(@WebParam(name = "idCar") int idCar) {
        return garageDao.getGarageForCarId(idCar);
}

/**
 *
 * @param owner
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public void addOwner(@WebParam(name = "owner") Owner owner) {
        ownerDao.addOwner(owner);
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Owner> getAllOwners() {
        return ownerDao.getAllOwners();
}

/**
 *
 * @param idGarage
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public Owner getOwnerForGarageId(@WebParam(name = "idGarage") int idGarage) {
        return ownerDao.getOwnerForGarageId(idGarage);
}

/**
 *
 * @param idCar
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public Owner getOwnerForCarId(@WebParam(name = "idCar") int idCar) {
        return ownerDao.getOwnerForCarId(idCar);
}

/**
 *
 * @param car
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public void addCar(@WebParam(name = "car") Car car) {

    carDao.addCar(car);

}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return carDao.getCars();
}

/**
 *
 * @param ownerId
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Car> getListCarsForOwnerId(@WebParam(name = "ownerId") int ownerId) {
        return carDao.getListCarsForOwnerId(ownerId);
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Car> getListCarsForOwnerName(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
        return carDao.getListCarsForOwnerName(name);
}

/**
 *
 * @param idGarage
 * @return
 */
@Override
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<Car> getListCarsForGarageId(@WebParam(name = "idGarage") int idGarage) {
    return carDao.getListCarsForGarageId(idGarage);
}

/**
 * Операция веб-службы
 * @param owner
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "sendMailToAdministrator")
public void sendMailToAdministrator(@WebParam(name = "owner") Owner owner) {
    postSender.send(owner);
}

/**
 * Операция веб-службы
 */
@Override
@WebMethod(operationName = "getAllGaragesForOwnerName")
public ArrayList<Garage> getAllGaragesForOwnerName(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
    return garageDao.getListGaragesForOwnerName(name);
}

@Override
@WebMethod
public Owner getOwnerByName(@WebParam(name = "name")String name) {
    return ownerDao.getOwnerForName(name);
}
```

}

Код клиентской стороны:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ClientServiceManagement client = new ClientServicesGarageManagement();
        private garage[] garagesClient = null;
        private car[] carsInGarage = null;
        private String header = "Пользователь не найден!";
        private String emptyField = "Пустое поле!";
        private String emptyMessage = "Пожалуйста, введите данные для поиска!";
        private garage garageChoosen = null;
        private String error = "Заполните поле марки машины или выберите гараж для добавления";
        private owner user = null;
        private MessageBoxButtons buttons;
        private DialogResult result;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            if (validateSearchBox(textBox1.Text.Length))
            {
               user = client.getOwnerByName(textBox1.Text);

                if(user == null)
                { String message = "Владельца гаража с именем " + textBox1.Text + " не найден. Измените параметры поиска";

                    buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                    result = MessageBox.Show(message, header, buttons);

                    if(result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                    }

                }
            try
            {
                label5.Text = user.name;
                initGaragesCount(user);
            } catch (NullReferenceException e1)
            {
                e1.ToString();
            }



        } else
        {
            buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            result = MessageBox.Show(emptyMessage, emptyField, buttons);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        car car = new car();
        if (textBox3.Text != "" && garageChoosen != null)
        {
            car.markAndModel = textBox3.Text;
            car.owner = user;
            car.garage = garageChoosen;
            client.addCar(car);
            initializeGarage(garageChoosen.id);
        }
        else
        {
            buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            result = MessageBox.Show(error, emptyField, buttons);
        }

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int indexChoose = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        garageChoosen = garagesClient[indexChoose];
        initializeGarage(garageChoosen.id);

    }

    private bool validateSearchBox(int length) {
        if (length != 0)
        { return true; }
        return false;
    }

    private void clearInformation()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void initGaragesCount(owner user)
    {
        garagesClient = client.getListGaragesByOwnerId(user.id);
        foreach (garage element in garagesClient)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(element.id + "  " + element.decription);
        }
    }



    private void initializeGarage(int idGarage)
    {
        carsInGarage = client.getCarsByGarageId(idGarage);
        foreach(car oneCar in carsInGarage)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(oneCar.id + "   " + oneCar.markAndModel);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Суть проблемы заключается, что при вызове поиска owner по имени на стороне сервиса ловит исключение

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[GarageServices]: Servlet.service() for servlet 

    GarageServices threw exception
    com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: com.ua.model.Owner@795dade6 -> com.ua.model.Garage@2c848766 -> com.ua.model.Owner@795dade6
```

А на клиентской - System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException

```
    System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   в System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowUnexpectedEndOfFile(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   в System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToEndOfFile()
   в System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ReadStartBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, EnvelopeVersion envelopeVersion, Boolean& isFault, Boolean& isEmpty)
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
   в System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
```

НО!!! Если сущность Owner которую запрашиваю - ни с кем не связанна - то исключения нет.
Как я почитал проблема в том что коллекции тяжко передаются. Нашёл решения, но они не подошли. Может что то не правильно делаю. Помогите в решении проблемы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Что происходит?

У вас `Garage` имеет ссылку на `Owner`, а `Owner` владеет коллекцией объектов типа `Garage`. Пока вы работаете с ними у себя на сервере - все хорошо, Hibernate нормально обращается с циклическими графами объектов.

Когда вы начинаете отдавать объекты клиенту, веб-сервис сериализует их в XML, начиная с корня, рекурсивно обходя все поля. Получается что-то вроде:

```xml
<Owner>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Foo</name>
  <garages>
    <Garage>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>barbaz</description> 
      <Owner>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <garages>
          <Garage>
            <id>1</id>
            <description>barbaz</description> 
            <Owner>
              <id>1</id>
              <name>Foo</name>
              <garages>
                <Garage>
                  <id>1</id>
                  <description>barbaz</description> 

   ... бесконечная рекурсия
```

Веб-сервис, впрочем, умеет замечать такие ситуации, поэтому просто выбрасывает исключение:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph
```

И отправляет клиенту пустой ответ, на что клиент тоже реагирует исключением.

---

### ОК, Делать-то что?

#### Вариант 1: Data Transfer Object

Вообще отдавать напрямую клиенту объекты из базы - не очень хорошая идея. Как правило там не нужны всегда и сразу все поля из всех таблиц.

Например, для отображения списка владельцев достаточно кода и имени, нет нужды тащить все их хозяйство сразу. Потом, скажем, по клику на конкретном владельце в списке можно открыть форму только с его гаражами и машинами.

Некоторые поля вообще не должны попадать на клиент никогда: представьте, что вы отдаете всех пользователей со всеми паролями.

Для разрешения этой ситуации используют паттерн Data Transfer Object (DTO). Для каждого класса модели БД или доменной модели создаются двойники с необходимым набором полей, без аннотаций JPA/Hibernate. В вашем случае это могут быть такие классы:

```
public class GarageListDto { // для списков
    private int id;
    private String decription;
    private String ownerName;
    private int carsCount;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}

public class GarageDto { // для формы
    private int id;
    private String decription;
    private OwnerListDto owner;
    private List<CarDto> cars;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}

public class OwnerListDto {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}

public class OwnerDto { 
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<CarDto> ownerCars;
    private List<GarageDto> ownerGarages;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

В общем ваша задача разрубть циклы в графе объектов, ориентируясь на логику клиента. Кроме того вам потребуется на сервере перегонять модели в DTO и обратно. Можно для каждой DTO сделать статический factory метод, принимающий модель и возвращащий DTO. И обратный ему метод. Можно использовать готовые решения для маппинга объектов в объекты, такие как [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

#### Вариант 2: настройка XML-сериализации

Если по каким-то причинам вы хотите выгружать клиенту весь граф объектов (а при таком подходе можно одним неловким запросом выкачать всю базу данных), воспользуйтесь средствами разрешения циклов XML-сериализатора.

В Java у вас скорее всего используется JAXB. Тут есть три варианта:

- Отметьте одно из полей, образующих цикл аннотацией `@XmlTransient`. Тогда рекурсия на нем не пойдет вглубь.
- Добавьте аннотацию `@XmlID` на ключевом поле объекта, на который надо сослаться и `@XmlIDREF` на ссылающемся поле. В этом случае JAXB не будет вкладывать XML представления объектов друг вдруга, а сделает плоский список и свяжет их по идентификаторам.
- Реализуйте в классах моделей интерфейс `CycleRecoverable`, чтобы программно задать поведение при обнаружении циклов.

Примеры см. тут: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html

Comment: Хороший ответ, но не помог полностью решить проблему. Вариант с сериализацией не работает. Первый вариант не в полной мере, второй вообще никаким образом.  В итоге получаю в консоли исключение `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ua.model.Garage.cars, could not initialize proxy - no Session` 
и ` Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details
Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
`
в браузере. Варианты исчерпал. Не знаю за что дальше браться.

Comment: Очевидно вы выполняете код после закрытия транзакции, поэтому ленивая инициализация, конечно, невозможна. Если вы пошли по темному пути выкачивания всей базы в XML вне сессии - вам нужно или забыть о ленивости и на всех связях `@ManyToOne` и `@OneToMany` выставлять `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, или JAXB сериализацию проводить явно в `@Transactional` методе, а из контроллера отдавать наружу уже String.

Comment: А почему первый вариант не помог? Других вариантов боюсь нет: вы либо как-то отдаете граф объектов с циклическими связями, либо как-то эти связи обрываете.

Comment: @Notafe вполне вероятно что проблема была связана с ленивостью, что не выходило. Сейчас пробую по новой. По результатам отпишусь.
Всё получилось) сменил инициализацию и всё как по маслу пошло. Спасибо)